# Calc 3 Density Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wrote down all the information I could for this problem but I'm having a very difficult time starting it.

Let $D =$ {$(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \le a^2, y\ge 0$} be a semi-circular lamina of radius $a$ above the $x$-axis whose density at any point is $K$ times the distance from the origin. Find the mass and center of mass of $D$.

I was pretty confident in myself until I saw how density was defined. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have the formula?  Can you apply them?  What have you tried and where is the trouble?

Comment: I wasn't really sure where to start, like I wouldn't have thought to demonstrate distance from the origin as you did. So it was really just starting off with that. I wasn't sure either which part of the problem to put under the double integral, but that makes sense as you're basing mass off of density.

Answer (score 0):

In Cartesian coordinates the mass and center of mass ($m, \vec s_0$) are found by the integrals: $$\begin{align}m={}&\iint_D \rho(\vec s)~\mathrm d \vec s \\[1ex]={}&\int_{-a}^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} K~\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[4ex]\vec s_0 ={}& \dfrac 1 m \iint_D \vec s \rho(\vec s)~\mathrm d \vec s\\[1ex]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix} ={}& \dfrac 1 m \int_{-a}^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} K~\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

However, it seems that converting to polar coordinates would have utility.  $$D_{\text{polar}}=\{(r,\theta): 0\leq r\leq a, 0\leq \theta\leq \pi\} \\ \rho(r,\theta) = K r \\ \mathrm d x~\mathrm d y = r~\mathrm d r~\mathrm d\theta$$